# How can I capture output from a CakePHP Shell

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

**Is there any way to capture a shell's output in CakePHP?**

I've written some shells that generates reports for a CakePHP 2.x application. I'm able to run the shells on a command line and view the output, however, now I'd like to email out the results of those shells.

I thought about using another shell as a wrapper and then using `$this->dispatchShell('shellname')` to capture its output, but it seems `dispatchShell` just runs the shell and dumps it's output to the CLI.

Comment: Just tested again, and it takes whatever the return was from the main method of the reporting shell, not the $this->out content.

Answer (score 2):

To have Shell output to a file, declare an output stream at your Shell's constructor. Here's an example to have stdout be a log file at your CakePHP's `TMP` dir (usually `app/tmp/`) on a file named `shell.out`:

```
<?php
class FooShell extends AppShell {

    public function __construct($stdout = null, $stderr = null, $stdin = null) {
        // This will cause all Shell outputs, eg. from $this->out(), to be written to
        // TMP.'shell.out'
        $stdout = new ConsoleOutput('file://'.TMP.'shell.out');

        // You can do the same for stderr too if you wish
        // $stderr = new ConsoleOutput('file://'.TMP.'shell.err');

        parent::__construct($stdout, $stderr, $stdin);
    }

    public function main() {
        // The following output will not be printed on your console
        // but be written to TMP.'shell.out'
        $this->out('Hello world');
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this in a shell, using CakePhp 1.3.6, but i get Class 'ConsoleOutput' not found in /path/sitemap.php on line 7. I am thinking ConsoleOutput is cakephp 2.0+?

Comment: This is great and exactly what I want but do you know if it's possible to APPEND to the file instead of overwriting it each time?