# writing output to a file with CakePHP shell

Tags: shell, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to just simply write "hello world" to a file, from a cakephp shell, with plans to eventually write a sitemap.xml file using our product models. I found this: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462829/how-can-i-capture-output-from-a-cakephp-shell) which got me started...

But i am thinking either ConsoleOutput is not supported in Cake 1.3.6 (which i'm using), or i need to include the class that holds it.

The error i get when trying to run the file from terminal:
**PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ConsoleOutput' not found in /public/vendors/shells/sitemap.php on line 7**

Here is my code:

```
class SitemapShell extends Shell {

public function __construct($stdout = null, $stderr = null, $stdin = null) {
    // This will cause all Shell outputs, eg. from $this->out(), to be written to
    // TMP.'shell.out'
    $stdout = new ConsoleOutput('file://'.TMP.'shell.out');

    // You can do the same for stderr too if you wish
    // $stderr = new ConsoleOutput('file://'.TMP.'shell.err');

    parent::__construct($stdout, $stderr, $stdin);
}

public function main() {
    // The following output will not be printed on your console
    // but be written to TMP.'shell.out'
    $this->out('Hello world');
}

}
```

Comment: You could just collect your output in a variable and file_put_contents() it. Would be easier IMO.

Comment: The shell in 1.3 is RADICALLY different than that in 2.x. Indeed, `ConsoleOutput` is not available in 1.3. I'd go with @mark's suggestion.

Comment: Ok, so i am guessing i don't even need the __construct then. I'll try this out and report back. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that ConsoleOutput didn't feature in CakePHP 1.3 - can you upgrade to a version 2.*?

If not you could just use regular PHP:

```
$fp = fopen('hello.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, 'hello world');
fclose($fp);
```

Hope this helps.

Toby